# How to use a Google Drive stored jpeg image in a replaceImage Google docs request?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am building a google document from Google docs API.
My doc is created from a template: copy the template in new location, replace texts, and replace images.

Everything is OK until I try to replace my images.

The images to put in the file are stored in a Google Drive folder.

So, I have 2 questions:
the first one is how to use replaceImage request with viewing URL of my image?
By using following code, I am facing a 400 error.

```
IDictionary<string, InlineObject> inlineObjects = doc.InlineObjects;
//Get the objet ID
string imageObjectId = inlineObjects.First().Value.ObjectId;

BatchUpdateDocumentRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest {
   Requests = new List<Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Request>()
};
var request = new Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Request {
ReplaceImage = new ReplaceImageRequest() {
    ImageObjectId = imageObjectId,
    Uri = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pmXP9TFolKMQoUlXHllvIrQPlZiDxId6"
}};
            
batchUpdateRequest.Requests.Add(request);
DocumentsResource.BatchUpdateRequest updateRequest = 
_docSercive.Documents.BatchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, fileId);
            
BatchUpdateDocumentResponse updateResponse = updateRequest.Execute();
```

Error:

```
Invalid requests[0].replaceImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden. [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid requests[0].replaceImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]'
```

and the second one is, how to industrialize this by retriving image URL from Google Drive API?
When I try getting it right now, I can only access image name and extension:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File f = _service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
```

am I supposed to use query params for this file.get call?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In my environment, when the image on Google Drive is publicly shared, the image can be used with ReplaceImageRequest. So for example, when other external URL is used, the same error occurs?